# How to create an entity in Apache Olingo?

Tags: java, apache, post, odata, olingo

OData's official tutorial shows how to create an entity: http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#create

I want to reproduce this within Apache Olingo using Templier's tutorial on manipulating data of OData v4 services with Olingo (https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/05/manipulating-data-of-odata-v4-services-with-olingo/)

Unfortunately, this tutorial is outdated and I am not able to create a successful `POST` request. Trying to execute my code yields `HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error`.

This is my code so far:

```
String serviceRoot = "http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/";    
String namespace = "Microsoft.OData.SampleService.Models.TripPin";

URI personURI = client.newURIBuilder(serviceRoot)
            .appendEntitySetSegment("People").build();      
FullQualifiedName personFqn = new FullQualifiedName(namespace, "Person");

ClientEntity personEntity = client.getObjectFactory().newEntity(personFqn);     
personEntity.getProperties().add(
            client.getObjectFactory().newPrimitiveProperty(
                    "username",
                    client.getObjectFactory().newPrimitiveValueBuilder()
                            .buildString("MaryGilbert")));
//same procedure for "FirstName" and "LastName", which are obligatory fields

ODataEntityCreateRequest<ClientEntity> req = client.getCUDRequestFactory().getEntityCreateRequest(personURI,personEntity);
ODataEntityCreateResponse<ClientEntity> res = req.execute();
```

What am I doing wrong? What can I do, to further identify/ debug the problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that property names are case-sensitive, so try using UserName instead of username. Also, you could use Fiddler in order to debug your issues.
This is the error for your use case:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error - {"error":{"code":"InternalServerError","message":"The property 'UserName[Nullable=False]' of type 'Edm.String' has a null value
```

Comment: Oh jeez, this was actually the problem. After adjusting  `username` to `UserName` I now receive a `Status Code 201`. Thank you very much. Further thank you for the tip with Fiddler. The tool looks very interesting.